# How to display SQL view query (from GeoServer) in OpenLayers

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers, wms, sql

I have written this SQL view code in GeoServer:

```
select *  
from pilot
where ((Price between %MinPrice% and %MaxPrice%) 
and (area between %MinArea% and %MaxArea%));
```

So according to the changed parameters this Request is produced as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pilot/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=pilot:FilterAreaPrice&styles=&bbox=535410.289995867,3949726.85999973,536327.370000143,3950801.26000122&width=655&height=768&srs=EPSG:32639&viewparams=MinPrice:1;MaxPrice:3;MinArea:1000;MaxArea:3000&format=application/openlayers&
```

My goal is that the user enters parameters in a form and then clicks on "submit" button and then results are displayed based on the parameters entered in my OpenLayers interface.

[image].

Additional information is attached

Comment: Does anything on this page help? http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html

Comment: if you change the format to image/png and the put the url in an img tag do you get a map?

Comment: Yes, when  I change URL with image/png I get map (png).    `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pilot/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=pilot:FilterAreaPrice&styles=&bbox=535410.289995867,3949726.85999973,536327.370000143,3950801.26000122&width=655&height=768&srs=EPSG:32639&format=image/png" alt="Smiley face" width="402" height="402">

</body>
</html>`

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  Always present both code and errors as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches.